# How to prove there is a natural number $n$, the first four digits of $n! = 2018$

Tags: number-theory, factorial

I have a question, that is how to prove there is a natural number $n$, the first four digits of $n!$ is $2018$.

Though I found similar question of OEIS sequence A019799,but I still don't know how to prove.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of [A019799](https://oeis.org/A019799).

Comment: There's a version of Stirling's formula which gives hard bounds of $n!$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation You want to get the lower bound above $2018\times 10^k$ and the upper bound below $2019\times 10^k.$  To do this, you get to adjust $n$ and $k$ as you please.

Answer (score 3):

If number $x$ has the form $$x = 2018\ldots,$$
then $$\log_{10} 2.018 \le\{\log_{10}{x}\} < \log_{10}2.019,$$
roughly $$0.3049211619< \{\log_{10}x\} < 0.3051363189;$$
where $\{z\}$ denotes *fractional part* of the number $z$.

---

This way, we should prove that the sequence
$$
S_n = \log_{10}(n!) =  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_{10}k
$$
contains element $S_{k_0}$, which fractional part belongs to the range $(0.3049211, \: 0.3051363)$.

---

Direct calculation shows that such $k_0$-candidates are:
$$670, \; 4906,  \; 7083,  \; 17787, \; \ldots$$
Therefore, the smallest $n!$ of the form $2018\ldots$ is $$670! = 2.0183491...\times 10^{1604};$$

WolframAlpha checking line:

```
 http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=670!
```

Comment: On the proof: maybe to show that the set $\{\log_{10}n!\}$ is dense on $[0, 1)$.

Comment: well, it seems to be another question that is how to prove the set {log10⁡n!} is dense on [0,1). ?